# Retrieving column names from a table without using ResultSetMetaData

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

Can we get table column info without using [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) object. Any other alternative?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using and give an example of what you want returned.  After all, the table column names could be considered metadata, so your question is unclear.

Comment: I mean to say without using resultsetmetadata object

Comment: Using `ResultSetMetaData` allows you to get that information in a database agnostic way. Why would you **not** want to use it?

Comment: Besides using DatabaseMetaData an alternative would be to query database specific information schemas/views.This is what most drivers do under the hood. However unless you need specific native information I would avoid it for portability reasons.

Comment: You get better answers if you say why.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column info of a table without running a `SELECT` statement by calling [`Connection.getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29).[`getColumns(null, null, "MyTable", "%")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).